# Android app communicating through .net project to Sql server database

Tags: c#, android, .net, sql-server

I want to connect my app to sql-server database, So i searched and found this answer in stackexchange:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/247293/guidance-on-android-type-app-to-connect-to-sql-server

from this i got to know how to connect; But my application has the following problems:
1. it's `https://` but it dosen't satisfy SSL requirements.
2. Its .NET 2.0 framework so it dosen't support `WCF`, `MVC` or `REST API`.

Is there any third party tool or any other method to connect an android application to sql-server database?

Comment: This is so broad question that it's quite impossible to answer. You could use so many tools. It's more about what you actually want to do, rarely you just want to "connect to a database." So please elaborate on the actual requirements.

Comment: i just know is any third party tool which should support .net 2.0 framework;and no SSL connections

Comment: Why not connect directly to sql server using jdbc?

Comment: Mine sql server enterprise manager